# Submitting an R job on a linux cluster

Tags: package

In submitting my R job to a cluster using the Rscript myscript.R command, I keep getting an error message saying the packages I have asked to load do not exist. However I have installed these packages onto a library on my profile. Do I have to set the working directory into the same pathway as the where the R packages are contained? I am genuinely puzzled by how to fix this error.

Thanks
Nikhail

Answer (score 0):

try to add directly the `install.packages` command in your script.  Like that, you're sure it will install properly:

for example add that at the beginning of your script (of course change "pacman;" for your real package and add one line per package):

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
```

I had this kind of problem before when the shell didn't call the good R for me (other version than the one I thought or 32 bits vs 64 bits).  Don't know if it's your problem however...

Comment: Thank you very much Bastien. I have solved the package problem. There was an issue with the CRAN as well as the specific package loading onto the cluster. However I have conducted my analyses using a different package and it has worked out fine.